# Decrypting file in VB.NET, process in use

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a file in VB using this code:

```
Try
            fsInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            fsOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
            fsOutput.SetLength(0)
            Dim bytBuffer(4096) As Byte
            Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0
            Dim lngFileLength As Long = fsInput.Length
            Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer
            Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream
            Dim cspRijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
            Select Case Direction
                Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                    csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                    cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                    csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                    cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            End Select
            While lngBytesProcessed < lngFileLength
                intBytesInCurrentBlock = fsInput.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)
                csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
                lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            End While
            csCryptoStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Clipboard.SetText(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        fsInput.Close()
        fsOutput.Close()
```

Heres the error I'm getting now:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\suffICE\Desktop\asdas.icevault' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at IceVaultFileOpener.Cryptography.fileCrypt.EncryptOrDecryptFile(String strInputFile, String strOutputFile, Byte[] bytKey, Byte[] bytIV, CryptoAction Direction) in F:\IceVault Developer Directory\IceVaultFileOpener\IceVaultFileOpener\icevaultfile.vb:line 91
```

I've already checked if it's possible if the file is opened in any other program, but it is not. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the fileshare parameter to your open statements.  Something like a `FileShare.Read` option, on the output file.  Without that parameter, they open in exclusive mode.

Also, put your .Close() statements after your `End Try` statement, so that they get closed no matter what happens.  Also, make sure you AREN'T actually catching an error in this routine, and thus skipping the closing of the files, so that when you try and decrypt it, it's not already open by the SAME process.  (Assuming you are attempting the Encrypt, and Decrypt in the same program, just for testing, etc...)

Comment: I've updated the code I used in my main post by added the FileShare.read options and i moved the close statements after the end try. Still getting the same error, it seems.

Comment: IT WAS A SPELLING ERROR THE WHOLE TIME! Thanks for helping me clean up my code though :P I'm sure some people, including myself, will still find oyour answer helpful!

Comment: Very cool Justin!  What was the spelling error??  I'm always curious to know what exactly it was when I attempt to help someone...  BTW, you should Up-vote my answer if you found it useful, along with tagging it as the "Accepted Answer" which you already did, and I thank you for that...  I hope I was of SOME help to you at least!  :)  I'll be around for more help if you need it, just HMU!

Comment: I upvoted your answer. The spelling error was just in the extension I was building into windows (".vault") because whenever it crypts the file it changes it to a .vault file. I accidentally wrote icevault in someplaces, because that was the name of the program. Silly mistake cost me a few hours :P

Comment: Hey.... We've all been there man!  That's why they pay us the <cough> big-bucks, right??  :)  Hey, I'm glad you got that worked out...  I'm actually interested in the whole project you're working on...  I'ma big fan of Cryptography...  Maybe we can get it touch off SO, and chat about it, and just BS about crypto stuff...  If you are so inclined...